# Access Network Folder using Different User Credential

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-xp, network-share

Domain Controller OS: Windows Server 2008 R2
Client OS: Windows XP, Windows 7

- Windows XP client name: `Client1`
- Windows XP client name: `Client2`

I had login as `abc.local\Q2020` on `Client1` and accessing other `Client2` shared folder via `Start` > `Run` > `\\Client2`

By defualt it is taking the Credential of the user which I have login i.e `abc.local\Q2020`, while accessing the shared folder on `Client2`.

I want that it must ask me a credential, so that i can give credential of different User, which has the rights of shared folder on `Client2`

Can you guide me - how can i give credential of different domain user while i am logged as `abc.local\Q2020`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Map a network drive to that network path and choose the option to use a different username and password.

Answer (score 11):

from the CLI:
net use * \\server\share password /user:domain\user

note the * will use the next available drive letter. If you prefer to use a specific driver letter, replace * with X:

Also note that you cannot simultaneously make two connections to a single server using two different user accounts. Type net use at the command prompt to see what connections are already open then net use \\server\share /delete to remove them before mapping the new drive.

Comment: You can also use * instead of the password parameter. This will prompt you to type in the password in a prompt that does not echo the characters. This keeps you from having to type your password in plaintext.

Comment: It's actually possible to connect to the same share using different accounts by using the FQDN and the IP address - Windows treats them as separate connections. So you could connect to \\Server1\Share, \\Server1.domain.com\Share and \\192.168.0.1\Share using three different sets of credentials.

Comment: @ChrisMcKeown - good one. I had forgotten about that.

Comment: @MDMarra, the danger of using \\server\share * to get prompted for password is that when you open Windows Explorer and begin typing the first few letters of the path... it shows the password in plaintext in the autocomplete dropdown for anyone looking at your screen to see.  Security failure on Microsoft's part. (Tested using Win7 SP1 with latest hotfixes as of Mar-14-2013).

Comment: @LeeGrissom The * in this example isn't to be prompted for the password.

Comment: @MDMarra, I think there's some confusion.  I was referring only to your comment dated "Jul 6 '12", not the answer by Paul. Using your suggestion, while the password will be masked in the CLI, it will appear in cleartext when navigating to the shared location via Windows Explorer.

Answer (score -1):

The connection to the share must be deleted. You can either logout and back in, or follow one of the `Net Use` procedures below without having to logout.

To delete all connections to a particular server, from Command Prompt type

```
 Net Use \\\servername /delete
```

replacing `servername` with the name or IP address of the computer or server.

To delete a connection to a specific share, from Command Prompt type "

```
 Net Use \\\servername\sharename /delete
```

replacing `servername` with the name or IP address of the computer or server and `sharename` with the name of the share.

Comment: Completely wrong! `net user ...` is for users, not shares. `net use \\server\share /delete` (with 2 backslashes, not 3!) or `net use * /delete` works to remove share mappings. But anyway, it may not be enough to remove stored credentials.